# Formulario con mapa interactivo para trazar ruta y calcular costos

Tags: reactjs, nextjs, mapa, vercel

Hola quiero poner en mi sitio web un mapa interactivo dentro de un formulario en el cual el usuario ponga en donde está y a donde quiere ir, para poder trazar la ruta y con los km totales sacar la cotización del servicio. Trate basarme en el sistema de una pag llamada "Urgegruas.com" pero me confundió mucho su encriptacion.

Conocen alguna manera tipo usando leaflet, mapbox, arcgis o maproute ya que no he dado con la manera de que el mapa se integre al formulario, intente hacerlo con react pero siempre topo con bibliotecas deprecated  intente algo así usando vercel para el back end pero sin éxito

```
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import "react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css";

const opcionesVehiculo = {
  Carro: {
    imagen: "",
    marcas: [
      "Toyota", "Honda", "Nissan", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Volkswagen", "Mazda", "Hyundai", "Kia", "Mercedes-Benz", "BMW", "Lexus", "Subaru", "Jeep"
    ],
    modelos: {
      Toyota: ["Corolla", "Camry", "Rav4", "Prius", "Highlander", "Land Cruiser"],
      Honda: ["Civic", "Accord", "CR-V", "Pilot", "Fit", "Odyssey"],
      Nissan: ["Altima", "Maxima", "Rogue", "Murano", "Pathfinder", "Armada"],
      Ford: ["Mustang", "F-150", "Escape", "Explorer", "Focus", "Fusion"],
      Chevrolet: ["Silverado", "Malibu", "Equinox", "Traverse", "Camaro", "Tahoe"],
      Volkswagen: ["Jetta", "Golf", "Tiguan", "Atlas", "Passat", "Arteon"],
      Mazda: ["Mazda3", "Mazda6", "CX-5", "CX-9", "MX-5 Miata", "CX-30"],
      Hyundai: ["Elantra", "Tucson", "Santa Fe", "Kona", "Palisade", "Venue"],
      Kia: ["Forte", "Optima", "Sorento", "Sportage", "Telluride", "Soul"],
      MercedesBenz: ["C-Class", "E-Class", "GLC", "GLE", "S-Class", "G-Class"],
      BMW: ["3 Series", "5 Series", "X3", "X5", "7 Series", "i8"],
      Audi: ["A3", "A4", "Q5", "Q7", "TT", "Audi R8"],
      Lexus: ["RX", "NX", "ES", "GX", "LX", "LS"],
      Subaru: ["Outback", "Forester", "Impreza", "Crosstrek", "Legacy", "Ascent"],
      Jeep: ["Grand Cherokee", "Wrangler", "Cherokee", "Compass", "Renegade", "Gladiator"]
    }
  },
  Camioneta: {
    imagen: "url_de_imagen_camioneta",
    marcas: [
      "Toyota", "Nissan", "Chevrolet", "Ford", "Honda", "Volkswagen", "Jeep", "GMC", "RAM", "Mitsubishi", "Hyundai", "Kia", "Mercedes-Benz", "BMW", "Audi", "Volvo", "Subaru", "Mazda", "Lexus", "Porsche", "Land Rover", "Jaguar"
    ],
        modelos: {
          Toyota: ["Rav4", "Hilux", "Land Cruiser", "Fortuner"],
          Nissan: ["X-Trail", "Frontier", "Armada", "Rogue"],
          Chevrolet: ["Equinox", "Trax", "Silverado", "Tahoe", "Suburban"],
          Ford: ["Escape", "EcoSport", "Ranger", "Explorer", "Expedition"],
          Honda: ["CR-V", "Pilot", "Ridgeline", "Passport"],
          Volkswagen: ["Tiguan", "Atlas", "Amarok", "Touareg"],
          Jeep: ["Grand Cherokee", "Wrangler", "Cherokee", "Compass", "Renegade"],
          GMC: ["Terrain", "Acadia", "Yukon", "Canyon"],
          RAM: ["1500", "2500", "3500", "Rebel"],
          Mitsubishi: ["Outlander", "L200", "Montero Sport", "Pajero"],
          Hyundai: ["Santa Fe", "Creta", "Tucson", "Palisade", "Kona"],
          Kia: ["Sportage", "Sorento", "Telluride"],
                MercedesBenz: ["GLC", "GLE", "GLA", "G-Class", "X-Class"],
                BMW: ["X3", "X5", "X7", "X6"],
                Audi: ["Q5", "Q7", "Q8", "Q3"],
                Volvo: ["XC60", "XC90", "XC40"],
                Subaru: ["Forester", "Outback", "Ascent"],
                Mazda: ["CX-5", "CX-9"],
                Lexus: ["RX", "NX", "GX", "LX"],
                Porsche: ["Macan", "Cayenne", "Panamera"],
                LandRover: ["Range Rover Evoque", "Discovery Sport", "Defender"],
                Jaguar: ["F-PACE", "E-PACE", "I-PACE"]
              }
            },
            Trailer: {
              imagen: "url_de_imagen_trailer",
              marcas: [
                "Utility", "Great Dane", "Wabash National", "Stoughton Trailers", "Fontaine Trailer", "East Manufacturing", "Manac"
              ],
              modelos: {
                Utility: ["3000R", "4000D-X", "3000R Multi-Temp", "VS2RA", "VS2DX"],
                GreatDane: ["Champion SE", "Freedom XP", "Aluminum Flatbed", "Everest TL"],
                WabashNational: ["DuraPlate", "Dry Van", "Refrigerated Van", "Flatbed", "Gooseneck"],
                StoughtonTrailers: ["Dry Van", "Refrigerated Van", "Flatbed", "Drop Frame Van", "Z-Plate"],
                FontaineTrailer: ["Infinity", "Velocity", "Revolution", "Magnitude", "Revolution H-Light"],
                EastManufacturing: ["Genesis", "Aluminum Flatbed", "Drop Deck", "Intermodal"],
                Manac: ["Drop Deck", "Flatbed", "Darkwing", "Extendable", "Step Deck"]
              }
            },
            Camion: {
              imagen: "",
              marcas: [
                "Freightliner", "Kenworth", "VolvoTrucks", "Peterbilt", "InternationalTrucks", "MackTrucks", "IsuzuTrucks", "HinoTrucks"
          ],
          modelos: {
          Freightliner: ["Cascadia", "M2", "114SD", "122SD"],
          Kenworth: ["W990", "T680", "T880", "W900"],
          VolvoTrucks: ["VNL", "VNR", "VHD"],
          Peterbilt: ["579", "567", "389", "337"],
          InternationalTrucks: ["LT Series", "RH Series", "MV Series", "CV Series"],
          MackTrucks: ["Anthem", "Pinnacle", "Granite"],
          IsuzuTrucks: ["N-Series", "F-Series", "FX-Series"],
          HinoTrucks: ["155", "195", "258", "268", "338"]
          }
          }
          };
```

Componente Formulario :

```
          const Formulario = () => {
          const [tipoVehiculo, setTipoVehiculo] = useState("");
          const [marca, setMarca] = useState("");
          const [modelo, setModelo] = useState("");
          const [año, setAño] = useState("");
          const [color, setColor] = useState("");
          const [llevaCarga, setLlevaCarga] = useState(false);
          const [enNeutral, setEnNeutral] = useState(false);
          const [requiereManiobra, setRequiereManiobra] = useState(false);
          const [numPasajeros, setNumPasajeros] = useState("");

          const handleTipoVehiculoChange = (tipo) => {
            setTipoVehiculo(tipo);
            setMarca("");
            setModelo("");
            setAño("");
            setColor("");
            setLlevaCarga(false);
            setEnNeutral(false);
            setRequiereManiobra(false);
            setNumPasajeros("");
          };

          const handleMarcaChange = (e) => {
            setMarca(e.target.value);
            setModelo("");
          };

          const handleModeloChange = (e) => {
            setModelo(e.target.value);
          };

          const handleFormSubmit = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
          };

          const renderFormFields = () => {
            if (!tipoVehiculo || !marca || !modelo) {
              return null;
            }

            let specificFields = null;

            switch (tipoVehiculo) {
              case "Carro":
                   specificFields = (
                <div>
                  {/* ... (código anterior) */}
                  <label>
                    Año:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={año}
                      onChange={(e) => setAño(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Color:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={color}
                      onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Marca:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={marca}
                      onChange={(e) => setMarca(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Modelo:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={modelo}
                      onChange={(e) => setModelo(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    En neutral?
                    <select
                      value={enNeutral ? "si" : "no"}
                      onChange={() => setEnNeutral(!enNeutral)}
                    >
                      <option value="no">No</option>
                      <option value="si">Si</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    ¿Requiere maniobra especial?
                    <select
                      value={requiereManiobra ? "si" : "no"}
                      onChange={() => setRequiereManiobra(!requiereManiobra)}
                    >
                      <option value="no">No</option>
                      <option value="si">Si</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Numero de pasajeros:
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      value={numPasajeros}
                      onChange={(e) => setNumPasajeros(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                </div>
              );
              break;
              case "Camioneta":
                specificFields = (
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      ¿Lleva carga?
                      <select
                        value={llevaCarga ? "si" : "no"}
                        onChange={() => setLlevaCarga(!llevaCarga)}
                      >
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="si">Si</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                  <label>
                    Año:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={año}
                      onChange={(e) => setAño(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Color:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={color}
                      onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Marca:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={marca}
                      onChange={(e) => setMarca(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Modelo:
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      value={modelo}
                      onChange={(e) => setModelo(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    En neutral?
                    <select
                      value={enNeutral ? "si" : "no"}
                      onChange={() => setEnNeutral(!enNeutral)}
                    >
                      <option value="no">No</option>
                      <option value="si">Si</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    ¿Requiere maniobra especial?
                    <select
                      value={requiereManiobra ? "si" : "no"}
                      onChange={() => setRequiereManiobra(!requiereManiobra)}
                    >
                      <option value="no">No</option>
                      <option value="si">Si</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    Numero de pasajeros:
                    <input
                      type="number"
                      value={numPasajeros}
                      onChange={(e) => setNumPasajeros(e.target.value)}
                    />
                  </label>
                </div>
                );
                break;
              case "Camion":
                specificFields = (
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      ¿Lleva carga?
                      <select
                        value={llevaCarga ? "si" : "no"}
                        onChange={() => setLlevaCarga(!llevaCarga)}
                      >
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="si">Si</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      ¿Requiere maniobra especial?
                      <select
                        value={requiereManiobra ? "si" : "no"}
                        onChange={() => setRequiereManiobra(!requiereManiobra)}
                      >
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="si">Si</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      Numero de pasajeros:
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        value={numPasajeros}
                        onChange={(e) => setNumPasajeros(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                );
                break;
              case "Trailer":
                specificFields = (
                  <div>
                    <label>
                      ¿Lleva carga?
                      <select
                        value={llevaCarga ? "si" : "no"}
                        onChange={() => setLlevaCarga(!llevaCarga)}
                      >
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="si">Si</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      ¿Requiere maniobra especial?
                      <select
                        value={requiereManiobra ? "si" : "no"}
                        onChange={() => setRequiereManiobra(!requiereManiobra)}
                      >
                        <option value="no">No</option>
                        <option value="si">Si</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                      Numero de pasajeros:
                      <input
                        type="number"
                        value={numPasajeros}
                        onChange={(e) => setNumPasajeros(e.target.value)}
                      />
                    </label>
                  </div>
                );
                break;
              default:
                break;
            }
            return specificFields;
          };

          return (
            <div>
              {Object.keys(opcionesVehiculo).map((tipo) => (
                <div key={tipo} onClick={() => handleTipoVehiculoChange(tipo)}>
                  <img
                    src={opcionesVehiculo[tipo].imagen}
                    alt={`Image of ${opcionesVehiculo[tipo].marcas[0]} ${tipo}`}
                  />
                  {tipo}
                </div>
              ))}
              <Carousel>
                <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
                  <label>
                    Tipo de vehículo:
                    <select
                      value={tipoVehiculo}
                      onChange={(e) => handleTipoVehiculoChange(e.target.value)}
                    >
                      <option value="">Selecciona un tipo</option>
                      {Object.keys(opcionesVehiculo).map((tipo) => (
                        <option key={tipo} value={tipo}>
                          {tipo}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
            </label>

            <label>
              Marca:
              <select
                value={marca}
                onChange={handleMarcaChange}
                disabled={!tipoVehiculo}
              >
                <option value="">Selecciona una marca</option>
                {tipoVehiculo &&
                  opcionesVehiculo[tipoVehiculo].marcas.map((marca) => (
                <option key={marca} value={marca}>
                  {marca}
                </option>
              ))}
          </select>
        </label>

        <label>
          Modelo:
          <select
            value={modelo}
            onChange={handleModeloChange}
            disabled={!tipoVehiculo || !marca}
          >
            <option value="">Selecciona un modelo</option>
            {tipoVehiculo &&
              marca &&
              opcionesVehiculo[tipoVehiculo].modelos[marca].map((modelo) => (
                <option key={modelo} value={modelo}>
                  {modelo}
                </option>
              ))}
          </select>
        </label>

        {renderFormFields()}

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </Carousel>
  </div>
);
}
export default Formulario;
```

Y para el mapa

```
import React, { useEffect, useReducer } from 'react';
import maplibregl from 'maplibre-gl';
import 'maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css';
import MapboxDirections from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions';
import "../components/map.css";
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_USER_POSITION':
      return { ...state, userPosition: action.payload };
    case 'SET_DESTINATION':
      return { ...state, destination: action.payload };
    case 'SET_LOADING':
      return { ...state, loading: action.payload };
    case 'SET_FIXED_MARKER_POSITION':
      return { ...state, fixedMarkerPosition: action.payload };
    case 'SET_FIXED_MARKER_POSITION_2':
      return { ...state, fixedMarkerPosition2: action.payload };
    case 'SET_FIXED_MARKER_POSITION_3':
      return { ...state, fixedMarkerPosition3: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const MapComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    userPosition: null,
    fixedMarkerPosition: { lng: , lat: },
    destination: null,
    loading: true,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets-v2/style.json?key=18Ju6g5GEgMRa5owSgUg',
      center: [state.fixedMarkerPosition.lng, state.fixedMarkerPosition.lat],
      zoom: 14,
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    });

    const directions = new MapboxDirections({
      accessToken: '',
      unit: 'metric', // 'imperial' or 'metric'
    });

    map.addControl(directions, 'top-left');

    // Event listener for user's position
    map.on('load', () => {
      map.addSource('user-marker', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'FeatureCollection',
          features: [],
        },
      });

      map.addSource('destination-marker', {
        type: 'geojson',
        data: {
          type: 'FeatureCollection',
          features: [],
        },
      });

      map.addLayer({
        id: 'user-marker',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'user-marker',
        paint: {
          'circle-radius': 10,
          'circle-color': '#007cbf',
        },
      });

      map.addLayer({
        id: 'destination-marker',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'destination-marker',
        paint: {
          'circle-radius': 10,
          'circle-color': '#ff0000',
        },
      });

      navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
        (position) => {
          const userPosition = [position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude];
          dispatch({ type: 'SET_USER_POSITION', payload: userPosition });
          map.getSource('user-marker').setData({
            type: 'FeatureCollection',
            features: [
              {
                type: 'Feature',
                geometry: {
                  type: 'Point',
                  coordinates: userPosition,
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },
        (error) => console.error(error),
        { enableHighAccuracy: true }
      );
    });

    // Event listener for clicks on the map
    map.on('click', (e) => {
      const { lng, lat } = e.lngLat;
      const destination = [lng, lat];
      dispatch({ type: 'SET_DESTINATION', payload: destination });
      map.getSource('destination-marker').setData({
        type: 'FeatureCollection',
        features: [
          {
            type: 'Feature',
            geometry: {
              type: 'Point',
              coordinates: destination,
            },
          },
        ],
      });

      // Set the waypoints using Mapbox Directions
      directions.setOrigin(state.fixedMarkerPosition);
      directions.setDestination(destination);
      directions.on('route', (route) => {
        // Access the route information if needed
        console.log(route);

        // Navigate to another page after setting the destination
        navigate('/resumen'); // Replace '/resumen' with the desired route
      });
    });
  }, [state.fixedMarkerPosition, state.fixedMarkerPosition.lat, state.fixedMarkerPosition.lng, state.userPosition]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="map" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 0, bottom: 0, width: '100%' }} />
      {/* Additional UI components and information can be added here */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, sugiero que trates de ser mas específico con respecto al problema que necesitas resolver, también puedes agregar mensajes de error y todo la información necesaria para que algún colega te apoye. La pregunta que estas publicando es muy general, por ejemplo `en que parte crees que el mapa no se integra al formulario` y deja indicado que parte del código crees que puede estar fallando.